# UIImagePickerController with the saved Video files

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

My application required UIImagePickerController with the Svaed Videos as well as Photo.
i am able to show cameralibrary waith the photos by following code

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType;

but Video are not there??

Its Resolved ......with following Code
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,
                                  nil];